# How do I set padding on a convolutional decoder?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm building a convolutional decoder that takes an input Tensor of size `1x96x4x4` and feeds it into three convolutional tranpose layers. How do I set `padding` and `output_padding` so that the output is of size `1x9x30x30`?

```
import torch

# Input.
x = torch.rand(1, 9, 30, 30) # input tensor of size 1x9x30x30

# Encoder.
encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Conv2d(9, 24, kernel_size=5, stride=2, padding=2),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Conv2d(24, 48, kernel_size=5, stride=2, padding=2),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Conv2d(48, 96, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
    torch.nn.ReLU()
)
z = encoder(x) # encoded tensor of size 1x96x4x4

# Decoder.
decoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(96, 48, kernel_size=3, stride=2),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(48, 24, kernel_size=5, stride=2),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d(24, 9, kernel_size=5, stride=2),
    torch.nn.Sigmoid()
)
x_hat = decoder(z) # how do I make this 1x9x30x30?
```

Comment: I think you cannot get `39x39` output shape via three `ConvTranspose2d` with kernel size 3 and stride 2.

Comment: What about `kernel_size=[3,5,5]`? That's how I built the encoder.